# Alamofire post request gives 404 Success response

Tags: ios, swift, post, http-status-code-404, alamofire

I have been experiencing issue as others. I have checked Stackoverflow and seen many others too have this issue. When the request works perfectly fine on Post man and returns 200 but returns 404 - Success in swift. Could any one get to know why is this happening and how to resolve it.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks again.

Comment: Very clear. You are not sending the same request as Postman.

Comment: NO, that's not the case. It is the exact same request. It happens only for couple of api's in my app where all the other api's work fine!

Comment: It says "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI (my_api)" .

Comment: **_It is the exact same request._** How have you checked it? Please show concrete proof with evidence. Generally 404 Not Found is caused by slight mistakes. I strongly recommend you to re-check your failing requests.

Comment: This could be caused by something that's often not shown in the URL when called, for exemple headers or the HTTP call type. Make sure you're using POST or GET properly